# Is it possible to parse only the second half of a file by starting at some rule other than the first rule?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have generated a JSON parser with ANTLR. To parse a JSON file, I must call the first rule in the JSON grammar:

```
parser = new JSONParser(...);
parser.json();
```

If I only want to parse a JSON array, can I skip all the JSON tokens up until the first token that starts an array and then call:

```
parser.array();
```

My guess is it won't parse until the end of the file, but instead it will stop at the end of the array in the JSON file. That's ok. But I'm not sure if it is allowed to call array() without any context, such as the correct JSON lexer mode.

Is there an example that describes how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `seek()` on your TokenStream before initiating the parse.  (I haven't directly tested it, but that should advance you TokenStream to the token where you wish to begin parsing).

Your intuition regarding calling the `parser.array()` method, and that it will parse until it has completed parsing the array that starts at your position in the token stream, is correct.  It will not parse to the end of the input.

If you don't know the index to seek to, perhaps you want to locate the first array, to start there, just call write a loop that calls `LA()` to get the next token (it's short for "Look ahead").  If it's not the '[' token, then `consume()` it.  If it is, then you're at the right position and can call `parser.array()` and will will parse just that array and return.

Comment: Do I have to call pushMode to start in the correct mode?

Comment: Modes only apply to tokenization.  Once you have the TokenStream to hand to the parser modes are no longer in play.

Answer (score 0):

Following up to Mike's answer, the lexer works independently of the parser, and you can't (easily) backup the lexer. But, you can work with CommonTokenStream to position where you want to parse:

```
    var lexer = new JSONLexer(str);
    var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
        var t = tokens.LA(i+1);
        var token = tokens.LT(i+1);
        if (token.Text == "[")
        {
            tokens.Seek(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    var parser = new JSONParser(tokens);
    var tree = parser.arr();
```

This code does a string comparison, but if you define a lexer symbol for '[', then you can break on the Type instead.